# Why doesn't isdigit() work?

Tags: c, debugging, scanf

I'm trying to make a program that generates a random number, asks the user to guess and then responds whether or not he got it right. For some reason, regardless of wether the user puts in a digit or not, it responds as if he didn't. Any ideas? thanks for helping out a beginner :)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<time.h>


main()
{
    char iRandomNum = '\0';

    int iResponse = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));

    iRandomNum = (rand() % 10) + 1;

    printf("Guess the number between 1 yand 10 : ");
    scanf("%d", &iResponse);

    if (isdigit(iResponse) == 0)
        printf("you did not choose a number\n");
    else if (iResponse == iRandomNum)
        printf("you guessed correctly\n");
    else 
        printf("you were wrong the number was %c", iRandomNum);
}
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit

Comment: `isdigit('1') == true; isdigit(1) == false;`

Comment: Well formatted question are easier to read for everyone. Your question would gain from that edit.

Comment: ok thank you! and what about the format needs to be improved? thank you

Comment: @fcconsuegraf see now I formatted it, doesn't it look easier to read?

Comment: @fcconsuegraf I see this is your first question, did you take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`isdigit()` takes the ascii value of a character and returns `0` if it's not a digit and non-`0` if it is.

You are passing to it an integer value which is not necessarily an ascii value, you don't need to check if it's a digit since you read it with `scanf()`.

If you want to make sure `scanf()` did read a number, check the return value of `scanf()` instead.

Try this

```
if (scanf("%d", &iResponse) != 1)
    printf("you did not choose a number\n");
```

instead of the `if (isdigit( ...`

One more thing, `main()` must return `int`.

Comment: The value in `iResponse` really can't be called "decimal", that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Thanks to the both of you! a quick follow up, why is what   `scanf()` reads not an ascii value? isn't an integer or a character ascii?also, i do not understand @unwind's comment. Thank you

Comment: with the `"%d"` specifier you are asking `scanf()` to read an integer decimal value. To read a character you need `"%c"`.

Comment: @fcconsuegraf: `scanf` reads characters from the input stream; the `%d` conversion specifier tells it to interpret those characters as an integer value.  For example, if the input stream contains the characters '1', '2', '3', '\n', `scanf` will read the first three characters, and then *convert* the character sequence `"123"` to the equivalent integer value `123` and store that value in `iResponse`

Comment: @fcconsuegraf A variable of type `int` holds an integer. At the machine level, it's very probably stored as ones and zeros, computers are binary after all. So, that value is not "decimal" (or "hex", or anything else except possibly binary). But all of those are just external representations the *number* is the same. You could write a function to print an integer as the corresponding number of `*` characters, that doesn't make the number itself change in any way.

Comment: @unwind I meant that the `"%d"` specifier reads numbers which are expressed in decimal representation.